# how to open up docker-compose up when given these issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost, airflow, airflow-webserver

```
docker-compose up has no configuration file provided: not found
```

this is given that I am in the directory where the `docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml` file is.

What should my next steps be to be able to open airflow in `localhost:8080`

Note: I am using windows

Looking at previous stackoverflow posts, I have also tried `docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up`, but it returns:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker-airflow-master-webserver-1 (f5311e617e9076840eeda2343df931c4716b9ae33817ba1ed91c10c272df9766): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated
```

Comment: As the error message says: there is already something running on port `8080`. Either [find out which process is using that port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows) and stop it, or change the host port.

Comment: @Turing85 I did a npx kill-port 8080 because it indeed said that I had two processes on TCP. That being said, when I run docker-compose -f .\docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up -d again, it gives me: 
error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker-airflow-master%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

My docker desktop also stopped and exited